# Irregular start-up/bootup behavior

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, login, unity-greeter

I am dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. It mostly works out great!
However, Ubuntu behaves reaaaaaally oddly when booted into. As soon as I leave GRUB, having selected to boot Ubuntu, randomly one of several things might happen:

1. Ubuntu boots into TTY, I wait for half a minute, then the login screen appears.
2. The login screen appears.

---

3. I log in, and Ubuntu loads my personal preferences (themes, icons, what have you)
4. I log in, and Ubuntu fails to load my preferences, instead showing me something that really resemble my user settings, but aren't really (different themes/icons etc)
5. I log in, notice that something failed to load, log back out, log back in and repeat this as often as necessary until finally I get to "my" homescreen.

Why? How? And most of all - how do I keep this from happening, so that the startup process runs smoothly as expected? Any ideas? Should I try a different login-manager (if such a thing exists)?

Thanks!

Comment: Point #1 (boot to TTY, GUI appears later) happens when in `/etc/default/grub`, you have set the option `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` instead of the default `...="quiet splash"`. After editing this file, calling `sudo update-grub` is necessary for the changes to take effect.